# custom export/Import for alfresco

Tags: import, export, alfresco

the obvious question is that is there any solution to export some alfresco contents which have a custom condition, for example export files which their create date is between a given date range?

the goal of this solution is:
1- to have a minimum mount of data volume in export/import action
2- in my weekly or monthly export/import action on backup alfresco server, I shouldn't have duplicate records for import action

thanks a lot for any kind of help

Comment: There are so many ways you could approach this, it would be helpful if you could specify what you've tried so far or at least what approaches you are considering.

Comment: as I know the only method to export alfresco contents is using Export item in action menu of any given folder, which exports all contents of that folder and it's sub-folders. as I explained my goals, this not useful for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use a library like OpenCMIS (Java) or cmislib (Python), both available from the [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org) project. Then use a CMIS query to restrict the data you want to export to a certain date range. If you want examples of CMIS queries, including ones that use date ranges, take a look at [this](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/blob/master/content/content-tutorial-cmis/src/main/java/com/someco/cmis/examples/SomeCoCMISDataQueries.java) Java example.

Another idea would be to use CMIS change tokens. Using this approach, you ask Alfresco what has changed since the last time your code ran. Alfresco responds back with a set of changes. You can then iterate over those changes and process them accordingly. The CMIS & Apache Chemistry in Action book has a change token example that uses Python to run a polling sync server between to CMIS repositories. The source code lives [here](https://github.com/fmui/ApacheChemistryInAction/tree/master/chapter9/python).

Both of these options use CMIS. If you would rather have a native Alfresco option you could write a custom action that runs on a schedule to call the export. Or, you could use the File Transfer Service to write files to a file system on a schedule.

If what you are really trying to do is back up your repository, don't use any of these options. Instead you should be following standard practice for backup up the repo which is to dump the database and backup the content store.

Comment: Hello and thanks Mr Potts, latest paragraph of your response is what I really want to do! but I ask you as an Alfresco Expert: As I know Alfresco is a famous Document Manager which can be used when huge mount of data storage and retrieve is needed. think of our distributed Organization structure: a central alfresco server is for Backup data and many of nodes should backup their content on central server, but because of bandwidth limitations,our nodes can't be sync with central server and we should use offline synchronization: we use weekly backup,and manually transfer them ...see next comment!

Comment: ...and manually transfer them to central server. what you do in this situation? do you export all of your contents?! if such, you have created a huge mount of data. in addition what do you do in import action with duplicate key errors?! thanks again for all of your response.

Comment: If you are doing a full backup of the repository and a full restore, there is no need to worry about duplicate key errors. Something you might be interested in is Toni de la Fuente's Backup and Recovery Tool (BART): https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-bart-backup-and-recovery-tool

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the Alfresco Replication Jobs to export your contents into a different repository.

In addition, you can export the contents to a file system using the FSTR feature.

Replication jobs use Alfresco Transfer Services that can be customised to only transfer some kind of content.